# How do i split a string in java from the second space?

Tags: java

I have this string:

"upload completed 12345"

In the java:

```
if (textforspeech.contains("upload completed"))
                                {
                                    String[] split = textforspeech.split(" ");
                                    textforspeech = split[0];
                                    status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progessStatus);
                                    status.setText(split[1]);
                                    MainActivity.this.initTTS();
                                }
```

The problem is that the split, split it from the first space.
So what i'm getting in the variable textforspeech is only "upload" and in split[1] i'm getting completed12345

But i need it to split it this way: "upload completed" in split[0] and in split[1] only 12345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\D]*)([\\d]*)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("upload completed12345");
        while (m.find()){
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just care for the `Upload completed` then you could do this:

```
String completed = "Upload completed 12345";
for(String s : completed.split("\\s(?!(?=completed))")) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

basicly it just checks, wheter a whitespace is followed by the word completed and wont split on this whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegExExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputString = "I want To Split String By Space";
        // spaceIndexToSplitString= 1 -> [I , want To Split String By Space]
        // spaceIndexToSplitString= 2 -> [I want , To Split String By Space]
        // spaceIndexToSplitString= 3 -> [I want To , Split String By Space
        int spaceIndexToSplitString = 3;
        System.out.println(splitString(inputString, "\\s", spaceIndexToSplitString));
    }

    /**
     * As per input in method, iterate for occurrence of finding String(space).
     * In loop we are checking if we have exact count of occurrence, then take
     * stringSplitIndex of occurrence and break the loop. By getting
     * stringSplitIndex of occurrence, split string from 0 to stringSplitIndex
     * and add into the list and take another subString from stringSplitIndex to
     * end length of inputString.
     * 
     * @param inputString
     * @param regEx
     * @param occurancePosition
     * @return
     */
    public static List<String> splitString(String inputString, String regEx, int occurancePosition) {
        List<String> splitedStringList = new LinkedList<String>();
        // Check if inputString is not null
        if (inputString != null && inputString.length() > 0) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
            int count = 0;
            int stringSplitIndex = 0;
            // Iterate while loop for finding regEx
            while (matcher.find()) {
                // increase count if found the matcher string(regEx)
                count++;
                // check if we found expected occurrence of regEx in given
                // inputString
                if (count == occurancePosition) {
                    // assign index position of occurrence regEx.
                    stringSplitIndex = matcher.end();
                    break;
                }
            }
            // add subString of input String into the list from String index
            // position 0 to according to our occurrence position
            splitedStringList.add(inputString.substring(0, stringSplitIndex));
            // add SubString from occurrence index position to end of the
            // inputString.
            splitedStringList.add(inputString.substring(stringSplitIndex));
        }

        return splitedStringList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't just blurt out code. Add some text to explain how the code answers the question.

Comment: As per input in method, iterate for occurrence of finding String(space).
In loop we are checking if we have exact count of occurrence, then take stringSplitIndex of occurrence and break the loop.
By getting stringSplitIndex of occurrence, split string from 0 to stringSplitIndex and add into the list and take another subString 
from stringSplitIndex to end length of inputString.